# Yacc : call to yyerror() without a real prototype

Tags: flex-lexer, yacc

I'm a beginner in yacc and seem to face some issues while compiling the yacc file.
What does the warning "call to yyerror() without a real prototype" mean?
How do I resolve it?

```
y.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
y.tab.c:287:5: warning: call to function ‘yyerror’ without a real prototype 
[-Wunprototyped-calls]

 ^
morse.y:19:6: note: ‘yyerror’ was declared here
yyerror(s)
  ^
y.tab.c:422:5: warning: call to function ‘yyerror’ without a real prototype 
[-Wunprototyped-calls]
yyoverflow:
 ^
morse.y:19:6: note: ‘yyerror’ was declared here
yyerror(s)
```

This is the yacc file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int valid=1;
%}
%token I AM
%%
msg     :       I"\n"{printf("End\n");
char message [20];
printf("Message:");
scanf("%s",message);
printf("Decoded : %s",message);
return;
}
;
%%
main(){
yyparse();
}
yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
}
yywrap ()
{
return 1;
}
```

~

Comment: That's what happens when you copy 30-year-old examples. Declare `yyerror` like this: `void yyerror(const char *s);`. Define it the same way: `void yyerror(const char *s) { fprint(stderr, "%s\n", s); }`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the solution. It worked